# Get speed of the ball to change directley from input in TextBox by buttonclick in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, buttonclick

I have a textBox where you fill in the speed for the ball. But when you fill in the value the speed dosen't chance until you click the button the next time (first you click to get it going, second clicks it stops so its acctually the third click I mean when it starts running again). Anyone that knows how I can get it to change directly when you click the button?

This is a pic of the "game": https://www.dropbox.com/s/xr05vh44y0u7zpl/game.jpg?dl=0

Bounce.cs (code-version of form app):

```
        // ball är en ny boll som skapas här genom klassen och filen Ball.cs. 
        // Här anges även vilken bild som bollen skall ha till utseende.
        // Det ställs även in vilken hastighet och position dessa skall utgå ifrån
        ball = new Ball(Image.FromFile("images/basketball.png"));
        panel.Controls.Add(ball);
        ball.Location = new Point(40, 320);
        ball.speedX = 1;
        ball.speedY = 1;
        running = false; // Ser till att bollarna inte rör på sig
        ball.Start();
    }



    // Delegering som skapats när man dubbelklickat på knappen go som skapat i de grafiska
    // Objektet sender är en event sender som skickar delegationen som en metod, vilket gör att knappen vid tryckning kallar deligationen som ger respons på klickningen
    // Detta för att delegationen ska använda rätt metod, Det skapas automatiskt en kod i designläget som ser ut så här: new System.EventHandler(this.goButton_Click);
    private void throwButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Sparar ner värdet som skrevs in för hastigheten
        speed = Convert.ToDouble(speedTextBox.Text);

        // Om running är sant sätts samma positioner och hastigheter för bollarna som utgångsläget i metoden Bounce(), alltså som i startläget
        // och sätter running till false, vilket innebär att bollarna stannar igen.
        // Menat att om man klickar på knappen när bollarna rör sig skall dessa stanna och gå tillbaka till utgångsläget som dem hade i appen från start
        if (running == true)
        {
            ball.Location = new Point(40, 320);
            ball.speedX = speed;
            ball.speedY = 1;
            running = false;
            speedTextBox.Clear();
            ball.Start();
            return;


        }

        // Om inte så sätts runnig till true för att representera att bollarna skall röra på sig
        running = true;

        // Följande kodrader gör så att metoden RunMe körs i en separat tråd (Befintlig kommentering)
        // så att det inte påverkar applikationens flöde. (Befintlig kommentering)
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(RunMe); // knyt metoden RunMe till worker (Befintlig kommentering)
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // starta (Befintlig kommentering)


    }

    // Deligation
    public void RunMe(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop som kontrollerar var bollarna befinner sig och vart dem skall hamna i olika beräkningar
        // Den tar bollarna b1 och b2 som skapats med hjälp av klassen Ball och använder sig utav olika metoder från klassen
        // Ser till att bollarna studsar på väggarna och botten av panelen (utrymmet dom är i)
        while (running)
        {
            if (ball.speedY > 0 && ball.Location.Y > panel.Size.Height - ball.Size.Height)
            {
                ball.BounceY();
                ball.posY = panel.Size.Height - ball.Size.Height;
            }
            if (ball.speedX > 0 && ball.Location.X > panel.Size.Width - ball.Size.Width)
            {
                ball.BounceX();
            }
            if (ball.speedX < 0 && ball.Location.X < 0)
            {
                ball.BounceX();
            }


            // Ser till att köra deligeringen MoveBallCallback med metoden MoveBall för respektive boll
            this.Invoke(new MoveBallCallback(MoveBall), ball);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

    }

    // Metod för att få bollarna att röra på sig, refererar till klassen Ball med parametern b 
    // och till metoden MoveBall i den klassen
    void MoveBall(Ball b)
    {
        b.MoveBall();
    }
```

Ball.cs (component class):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
namespace Bounce
{
class Ball : Label
{
    // Variabler
    public static double gravity = 0;
    public static int collissions = 0;
    public double speedX, speedY;
    public double posX, posY;

    // Konstruerare som ritar upp bollarna genom att använda Image från System.Drawing.Image klass
    public Ball(Image image)
    {
        Image = image;
        BackColor = Color.Transparent; // Sätter bakgrundsfärgen till genomskinlig på kontrollen
        Size = new Size(60, 60); // Sätter storleken på kontrollen
        Visible = true; // Ser till att bollarna syns
    }

    // Metod som får bollen att röra på sig
    public void MoveBall()
    {
        // Lägger till graviteten på hastigheten av Y-vinkeln och lägger på hastigheterna på respektive position
        speedY += gravity;
        posX += speedX;
        posY += speedY;
        Location = new Point((int)(posX), (int)(posY)); // Sätter den nya platsen för bollen till de nya positionerna
    }

    // Metoderna BounceY() och BounceX() ser till att inte ändra graviteten och farten medan dem studsar genom att ta bort de som lades till i metoden MoveBall()
    public void BounceY()
    {
        speedY = -(speedY + gravity); // dont add gravity when bouncing
    }
    public void BounceX()
    {
        speedX = -speedX;
    }

    // Metod som lägger till nuvarande position till variablerna för positionerna (för posX respektive posY)
    public void Start()
    {
        posX = Location.X;
        posY = Location.Y;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not change the headline if you do not get what I was asking.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. You're creating a new worker everytime you click on the button. This is kinda wrong. Make the backgroundworker a class field and call RunWorkerAsync once to let the ball animate. You need to support cancellation if you want the worker to stop animating.

Comment: Can you please expound what you mean that I need to do? its sounds smart when you say it, but Im not totally shore how you mean I should do @Sievajet

Comment: You need to rewrite your code by instantiating only one worker and not everytime you click on the throw button. Everytime you set running to false, the worker goes out of its loop and gets completed. the programflow is just wrong. read the msdn docs how to work with a worker and work from there

Comment: I dont think it is that easy to read my self to know exactly how to do it in another way.. That part is not event my code, but something my teacher done.I would love if someone had the time to explain a bit what I need to do, do I need to to a method, a deligate or how cna I get it outside so its not in the click but still get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
if (running) {
   code  ...

   returns from the method. 
}
```

seems to be a trigger to stop the ball. So your

```
ball.speedX = speed;
```

is set when the ball stops, not when it starts. Just move the `ball.speedX = speed` below the if statement and you should be fine. That part runs when the animation starts.

@Sievajets comment is valid. There is a real possibility you start two workers manipulating the same ball object.